# getting the field values of content types from drupal

Tags: drupal-7

Here I want to know how to get the field values of my custom content type 'mypop'. I tried all methods in google but I don't know how to use, for example i tried function node_load, I can't able to know where to write this function, what are the parameters and tried EntityFieldQuery too. Can I know the how to do it in brief explaination.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a very broad question. Assuming you have the content type 'mypop' created already, think the easiest steps for you would be to:

1. Make sure you create some content of that content type
2. Customize the "Manage Display" on that content type and make sure the fields you want are set to visible there

Once you do this, those fields should be visible when you view the nodes of that content type already. If you want to further customize the view, you should probably customize the template file for that specific content type (there's other options but trying to keep this as simple as possible).

To do this, copy the "node.tpl.php" file you'll find on the modules/node folder to your theme templates folder and change it's name to be "node--mypop.tpl.php".

That way, you'll override Drupal's default display template for that specific content type only. Now you can basically tweak it into anyway you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Alberto. Its working now! I have another issue too, it also got cleared and now its working fine !Another issue  is javascript called automatically when I open views edit for other contents. Now by doing overriding this template file, it also gets cleared. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

node_load take node id. So in order to use `noad_load()` function, you should first retrieve node ids. Better if you use `noad_load_multiple()`.

```
// Query all of the nids of a particular content type.
  $nids = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition('type', 'Article', '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();

  // Get all of the article nodes.
  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

You can see the result by calling `print_r($nodes)`. Just write a normal function in you .module file or .inc file. Call it anywhere, your choice. say, in menu callback.